# Weird clustering output (scikitlean kmeans)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I have an imbalanced dataset with four labels in total. Two of them have a much higher appearance frequency than the other two. I have nearly one million observations.

I'm trying to understand the data components a bit better by exploring with `sklearn.cluster.kmeans` clustering.

Here's my data:

```py
print(X)
[[68.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
 [18.  1.  1. ...  1.  0.  0.]
 [18.  1.  1. ...  0.  0.  0.]
 ...
 [59.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
 [48.  1.  0. ...  0.  0.  1.]
 [47.  1.  1. ...  0.  0.  0.]]

print(y)
[1 2 3 ... 3 2 3]
```

The observed labels have four levels (ordinal variables 0 - 3).

Here's my code:

```py
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
X_scaled = scaler.transform(X)

algo1 = KMeans(n_clusters = 4)
y_pred = algo1.fit_predict(X_scaled)

mglearn.discrete_scatter(X_scaled[:, 0], X_scaled[:,1], y_pred)
plt.legend(["cluster 0", "cluster 1", "cluster 2", "cluster 3"], loc = 'best')
plt.xlabel("Feature 0")
plt.ylabel("Feature 1")
```

[image: Four clusters]

This looks weird, so I tried 3 clusters.

```
algo2 = KMeans(n_clusters = 3)
y_pred2 = algo2.fit_predict(X_scaled)
mglearn.discrete_scatter(X_scaled[:, 0], X_scaled[:,1], y_pred2)
plt.legend(["cluster 0", "cluster 1", "cluster 2"], loc = 'best')
plt.xlabel("Feature 0")
plt.ylabel("Feature 1")
```

[image: Three clusters]

And then 2 clusters

```
algo3 = KMeans(n_clusters = 2)
y_pred3 = algo3.fit_predict(X_scaled)
mglearn.discrete_scatter(X_scaled[:, 0], X_scaled[:,1], y_pred3)
plt.legend(["cluster 0", "cluster 1", "cluster 2"], loc = 'best')
plt.xlabel("Feature 0")
plt.ylabel("Feature 1")
```

[image: Two clusters]

I'm trying to figure out what exactly is happening to the clustering. Is there an alternative way that I could better understand the data structure?

Comment: You have more than 1 feature used for the clustering, and Feature is binary so you will not see the usual "clusters" on a scatter plot. You need to do a dimension reduction on your data, and plot

Comment: Do you mean a dimensionality reduction before the clustering or after the clustering but before the plotting?

Comment: after the clustering. In any case, the dimension reduction would be independent of the clustering. You can do a PCA on `X_scaled`, and plot the first 2 PCs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention how many features you have, but by the looks of it, `X` has way more than just two variables. In your code, you are visualizing the clusters using only two features while `algo1` used more variables than that.

In particular, you are visualizing the clusters using `Feature 1`, which appears to be binary (only takes on the values - 1 and 1 ), so it's not that the clustering is unsuccessful; you are simply visualizing the clusters under a very limited number of features.

By plotting in 2-D, you are limiting yourself to seeing the clusters as a function of only two variables, so there's a chance you'll be missing out on some relationships that are only visible in 3-D or even higher dimensions. If you wish to carry on this way, I recommend plotting `Feature 1` against all other features, then `Feature 2` against all other features, and so on. This way, you will visualize the clusters under all combinations of size two and perhaps this will help you understand the relationship between certain pairs of features and the cluster they belong to.

Remember also that `KMeans` is an unsupervised algorithm, so the clusters are not necessarily related to the labels in `y`. The results simply mean that the observations in each cluster are similar to each other in terms of distance to the centroid.

Comment: I don't think the issue is the name. "Feature 1" and "Feature 0" are just the name I gave to the axes.

Comment: You are always plotting `X_scaled[:,0]` against `X_scaled[:,1]`. Regardless of the names of the axes, you are always plotting the first feature against the second one.